# How can I send data onclick from form in jsp page to servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

I have .jsp page where i display some data from DB(Table seria[id, name, description, photo]). How to send id to servlet, when user click on area with photo and text? Now anywhere i click, servlet get seria_id=1. Screenshot of site http://joxi.ru/krDLaDYS07pwNr My form here->

```
<form id="myform" action="/seria" method="post">
    <%Iterator itr;%>
    <% LinkedList<Seria> data = (LinkedList<Seria>) request.getAttribute("data");
    Seria seria;
    for (itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
        seria = (Seria) itr.next();
    %>
    <input type="hidden" name="seria_id" value=<%=seria.getId()%>>
    <table onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <h3 align="center">Серия &laquo;<%=seria.getName()%>&raquo;</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                    <img src="/img/<%=seria.getPhoto()%>" width="60%" alt="cars" hspace="20%">
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=seria.getDescription()%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    <%}%>
</form>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SeriaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.SeriaServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SeriaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/seria</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Enumeration en=request.getParameterNames();
    while(en.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Object objOri=en.nextElement();
        String param=(String)objOri;
        String value=request.getParameter(param);
        System.out.println("Parameter Name is '"+param+"' and Parameter Value is '"+value+"'");
    }
}
```

Always prints "Parameter Name is 'seria_id' and Parameter Value is '1'"
Project on github om the moment of question.
https://github.com/sasha361322/jsp-servlet/commit/aaf869ccde54d53e16f964a6db9786c27def8eab

Comment: check roytuts.com/xchart-using-ajax-jsp-and-servlet/ & roytuts.com/highchart-using-ajax-jsp-and-servlet/

Answer (score 0):

If you want get the value through

```
    getParameter(name);
```

Then you should send the values URL 
i.e in your case action URL is /seria

So you send the value as

```
/seria?parmName1=ParmaValue1&parmName2=ParmaValue2
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution. Instead of one form, now i make for every seria each one.

```
<%Iterator itr;%>
                            <% LinkedList<Seria> data = (LinkedList<Seria>) request.getAttribute("data");
                            Seria seria;
                            for (itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
                                seria = (Seria) itr.next();
                            %>
                            <form id="<%=seria.getId()%>" action="/seria" method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="seria_id" value=<%=seria.getId()%>>
                                <table onclick="document.getElementById('<%=seria.getId()%>').submit();">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <h3 align="center">Серия &laquo;<%=seria.getName()%>&raquo;</h3>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="50%">
                                                <img src="/img/<%=seria.getPhoto()%>" width="60%" alt="cars" hspace="20%">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <%=seria.getDescription()%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                            <hr>
                            <%}%>
```